# listing files on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to list all files i have on my phone.

I have two files in my solution. One database file and one pdf file.

With this code i only get the database file listed. How can i list PDF files with IsolatedStorage?

```
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string searchPattern = "\\" + "*";
                string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames(searchPattern);
            }
```

Comment: you can't break outside your app to look at other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf-file is not stored in isolated storage but in your xap You can't enumerate files in your xap.

To be able to list the PDF, you need to copy it to isolated storage first. (for example the first time your app runs)